# How to insert an upward arrow in MATLAB Graph?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to insert an arrow showing upward direction in MATLAB? How to do this? 
Arrows are not included in the marker style in MATLAB documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow can be inserted using `text`.
However, position is required to be given for appropriate placement.

```
text(0.1,0.7,'\uparrow', 'color' ,'r','FontWeight','bold', 'Fontsize', 16);

text(0.2,0.7,'\downarrow', 'color' ,'r','FontWeight','bold', 'Fontsize', 16);

text(0.3,0.7,'\rightarrow', 'color' ,'r','FontWeight','bold', 'Fontsize', 16);

text(0.4,0.7,'\leftarrow', 'color' ,'r','FontWeight','bold', 'Fontsize', 16);
```